# How to move description in list page magento 2.4

Tags: product-list, magento2.4.1, list.phtml, product-description

I want to move the sku after description in list page.
https://prnt.sc/DFlrsqO-tC4A

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to move the SKU:

```
 <move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.info.description" after="-"/>
```

or you can move anywhere where you want, just change the destination.

```
 <move element="product.info.sku" destination="<whereYouWantToMove" after="-"/>
```

Clear cache and check

Comment: want to move in category page
https://prnt.sc/UzKQFUZYs-jj

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work.

```
 <move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/UzKQFUZYs-jj